# Flutter audioplayers: ^2.0.0 error Unhandled Exception: Unable to load asset: assets//data/user/0/com.xxxx.xxxx/cache/flip.mp3

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-audioplayers

I'm trying to use  audioplayers: ^2.0.0,but i got this error, how to solve it?please!

[image: 1]

**pubspec.yaml**

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/audio/
```

**Code**

```
 Future setAudio() async {
    AudioPlayer audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();
    audioPlayer.setReleaseMode(ReleaseMode.loop);

    AudioCache audioCache = AudioCache(prefix: 'assets/audio/');

    final url = await audioCache.load('flip.mp3');
    audioPlayer.setSourceAsset(url.path);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use the full path in `setSourceAsset`, and since you've already set a prefix for the cache you kust have to write the filename:

```dart
audioPlayer.setSourceAsset('flip.mp3');
```